# Receiving TCP data on html5 page

Tags: javascript, tcp, websocket

I have a web site PHP based at mywebsite.com. I want to create a special page to receive a TCP data from another server. Is it possible to achieve this using javascript?

I have no control over the server that is sending TCP data, I can just configure its domain:port to point to mywebsite.com.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send some data from browser to server use "ajax"

```
 but not tcp its http
```

in html5 a special method called websocket available.
its used to send recive tcp data.

```
 but "websocket" must available in both "server" and browser.
```

you want websocket then here a tutorial

http://tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

but it must be implemented in server and browser.
you said you have no controll over server.then its not possible

if websocket already in server.then possible ..by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in javascript (javascript in executed in the browser not in mywebsite.com):

You'll have to open a server socket on mywebsite.com then redirect data to your webpage (via websocket maybe).